# Django select_related Not Working as Expected

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-admin, django-select-related

I have 2 classes, Country and Coordinates. When making an API call to the Country table, I would like the API (using DRF) to return the related Coordinate information as well.

By default, the following is understandably returned (*localhost:8000/api/country/*):

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "TestCountry",
    "coordinates": 1
}
```

The problem is that after implementing select_related in my views.py file, and modifying the CountrySerializer as well, the output remains exactly the same. I had expected something like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "TestCountry",
    "coordinates": {
        "longitude": 123,
        "latitude": 456,
    }
}
```

Or even this would suffice:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "TestCountry",
    "longitude": 123,
    "latitude": 456,
}
```

And here are the relevant code in models, views, and serializer files.

```
class Coordinates(models.Model):
    longitude = models.DecimalField()
    latitude = models.DecimalField()

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    coordinatesID = models.ForeignKey(Coordinates, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Coordinates", db_column="CoordinatesID", blank=True, null=True, related_name="coordinates")

class CountryViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Country.objects.select_related('coordinatesID').all()
    serializer_class = CountrySerializer

class CountrySerializer(DynamicFieldModelSerializer):
    longitude = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='coordinates.longitude')
    latitude = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='coordinates.latitude')

    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = '__all__'
```

Additionally, in the Country table, I specified the *related_name="coordinates"*, however *select_related* does not recognize this option, and I still have to use *"coordinatesID"* to reference the coordinate table. Is this a bug or related to incorrect implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `related_name` is used to access the relationship in reverse from the `Coordinates` model side to `Country` side not the opposite.

so in the `select_related` you can use all fields and relationships that are defined on the Model itself, so for `Country` model if you defined coordinates relationship as `coordinatesID` you will need to do like this

```
queryset = Country.objects.select_related('coordinatesID').all()
```

and to use in the serializer

```
longitude = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='coordinatesID.longitude')
latitude = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='coordinatesID.latitude')
```

also using a field name like `coordinatesID` is not great naming convention in django since you would have a property like `coordinatesID.id` which is not very clean.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/